# Sequential file name in NLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I would like my file name to be changed dynamically and include a sequence number. The file name should be changed (increment the number) at each archiving process/log rotation.
When archiving the file, the archive file name should be the same as the file name with the sequence number (before the increment).

Starting with file name to be 'file.log.1', when archiving the archive file name will be 'file.log.1' and the file name will be changed to 'file.log.2'.
The next archive file name will be 'file.log.2' and so on...

Is it possible using NLog?
Didn't find any clue in the web or the NLog source code.

Comment: Did you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40644252/3990896)?

Comment: See also [Archive Numbering Examples](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples#archive-numbering-examples)

Comment: yep and yep. The answer/example there is with writing to the same file target with the same name.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I don't see the difference with the linked values. Also writing the same file from 2 targets in performance wise not recommend. The same file from different loggers isn't a problem!

Comment: @Julian In which of the above links the target file name change with a sequential number? I can't find it...
I will need same file diff loggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I implemented a custom FileTarget that answer my needs:

```
internal sealed class CustomFileTarget : NLog.Targets.FileTarget
{
    private const int _maxOldFilesToKeep = 10;

    private readonly string _directory;
    private readonly long _fileMaxSize = (long)10.Megabytes().Bytes;
    private readonly string _fileNamePrefix;

    private int _sequential;

    private string FullFileName => $"{Path.Combine(_directory, _fileNamePrefix)}.{_sequential}.log";

    public CustomFileTarget(string directory, string fileNamePrefix)
    {
        _directory = directory;
        _fileNamePrefix = fileNamePrefix;
        _sequential = GetLatestSequence() ?? 0;

        ConcurrentWrites = false;
        FileName = FullFileName;
        KeepFileOpen = false;
    }

    protected override void Write(IList<AsyncLogEventInfo> logEvents)
    {
        base.Write(logEvents);

        if (GetFileSize() >= _fileMaxSize)
        {
            ChangeName();
            DeleteOld();
        }
    }

    private long GetFileSize() =>
        new FileInfo(FullFileName).Length;

    private void ChangeName()
    {
        _sequential++;
        FileName = FullFileName;
        LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
    }

    private void DeleteOld()
    {
        var fileNamesAndSequences = GetFileNamesAndSequences();
        if (fileNamesAndSequences.Count() > _maxOldFilesToKeep + 1)
        {
            fileNamesAndSequences.Take(
                fileNamesAndSequences.Count() - _maxOldFilesToKeep + 1)
                .ForEach(
                    _ => Directory.Delete(Path.Combine(_directory, _.FileName)));
        }
    }

    private int? GetLatestSequence()
    {
        var fileNamesAndSequences = GetFileNamesAndSequences();
        return fileNamesAndSequences.Any()
            ? fileNamesAndSequences.Last().Sequence
            : (int?)null;
    }

    private IEnumerable<(string FileName, int Sequence)> GetFileNamesAndSequences() =>
        Directory.GetFiles(_directory, $"{_fileNamePrefix}*.log").
            Select(
                _ =>
                {
                    var fileNameParts = _.Split('.');
                    return (_, Sequence: int.Parse(fileNameParts[fileNameParts.Length - 2]));
                }).
            OrderBy(_ => _.Sequence);
}
```

Comment: Note: You don't need `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()` here.

Comment: Also please note that you're multiple times running over `GetFileNamesAndSequences()` (Any, Last, Count). Not do good for performance